# Find $\mathbb{E}(W_{1}|\min(W_{1},W_{2}))$ for $W_1$ and $W_2$ i.i.d. exponential

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $W_{1},W_{2}$ be independent, exponentially distributed random variables, $\mathbb{E}(W_{i})=\lambda$. Find $\mathbb{E}(W_{1}|\min(W_{1},W_{2})).$

I think I have the correct solution, but it's based solely on intuition.

Let $X=\min(W_{1},W_{2})$. $$\mathbb{E}(W_{1}|X)=\mathbb{E}(W_{1}|X=W_{1},W_{1}<W_{2})\mathbb{P}(W_{1}<W_{2})+\mathbb{E}(W_{1}|X=W_{2},W_{2}<W_{1})\mathbb{P}(W_{2}<W_{1})=\frac{1}{2}(X+\mathbb{E}(W_{1}|W_{1}>X))$$
And now the remaining expectation can be obtained by computing one integral and dividing it by the probability that the random variable $W_{1}$ is greater than $X$. Is this approach correct? Could someone explain, in mathematical terms, why the decomposition in the first line of the above reasoning is valid? (if it is).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/771620/321264

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loss of memory property of the exponential distribution implies that, conditionally on $X$, $W_1=X$ with probability $\frac12$ and $W_1=X+W$ with probability $\frac12$, where $W$ is independent of $X$ and exponential with parameter $\lambda$. Hence,
$$
\mathbb E(W_1\mid X)=\frac12X+\frac12(X+\mathbb E(W))=X+\frac1{2\lambda}.
$$